# How to make snowballs invisible?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to implement, mostly for entertainment sake, but also for a potential "magic" system later on in the game, a way to make snowballs invisible while in the air. I'm on Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, using

```
/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ summon skeleton ~ ~-4~
```

to spawn, well, skeletons in the wake of the snowball as it flies, for an undead summoner-type feel, and I know you can set it up to detect when the snowball hits the ground and summon fire there, a "fireball spell" if you will, but the only problem with both of those is that you have to deal with the snowball itself flying at you just before the effect.

It's a cool feature nonetheless, but it's certainly a bit immersion breaking when you see a snowball before the wave of undead or a sea of flames.
I tried using `/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ effect @e[type=snowball] invisibility 100 10 true`, but the system cannot register the snowball. I tried giving it a unique name, but then I couldn't figure out how to search for entities with unique names.

I figure if I can identify the item with its unique name it might work, but even then I'm skeptical. I figure my best bet is to ask around and see if anybody has already come up with a solution for this or might potentially have some ideas for me to test out. As of right now, my only option seems to be making a new texture pack with a more immersive snowball style, but then people will just be confused when they go to dig up snow and get a fireball looking thing.

Comment: I think in MCJava you could change the item that the snowball renders to something invisible, but that's not possible in MCBE. So it might be impossible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In ''Minecraft: Bedrock Edition'', entities like snowballs cannot have effects, so there is no way to easily hide the snowball. One thing you can do is make a texture pack to hide the snowball, or have an invisible entity (armor stand) be teleported in front of the snowball (using ^ and facing) then have the entity be teleported in the direction the snowball was heading. This system is quite complex and can use a lot of commands but there are the only ways I know that could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get a repeating command block then input the command `/effect @e[type=snowball] invisibility 999999 1 true` and set the command block to always active and no tick delay.

(I suggest turning command block output to false with `/gamerule commandblockoutput false`)

You can still see the snowball in your inventory, but not after it is thrown

Comment: Are you sure that works on bedrock? Read the question, please.